# Create an AspMvc Route for Slug that leaves no trails

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing, slug

Lets say I have three entities: `Events`, `People` and `Pictures`, also `Events` has a slug property to beautify my urls.

I want to route events by slug, and explicitly route all other Entities. Also, I want no default routing.

- / => EventController/Index/{searchFilder}
- /{slug} => EventController/Details/Slug
- /Event/{action} => EventController/{action}
- /Profile => ProfileController/{action}/{id}
- /Picture => PictureController/{action}/{id}

The event controller is mapped three times. Using a slug to get existing events, without parameter for the index page of the site and with other actions so I can perform Create for example (there is no slug at that time).

Having that in mind I map like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Profiles",
    url: "Profile/{userName}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Profile", action = "Index", 
                    userName = UrlParameter.Optional });

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Pictures",
    url: "Picture/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Picture",  action = "Index",
                    id = UrlParameter.Optional });

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "EventBySlug",
    url: "{slug}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Event", action = "Details"} );

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Events",
    url: "Event/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Event", action = "Index",
                    id = UrlParameter.Optional } );

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "",
    defaults: new { controller = "Event", action = "Index" } );
```

This goes fine, until I create an ActionLink for the main page (in my layout)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Events")
```

If I click the Home link while I am viewing the Event `/christmass-2013` I go to  `/christmass-2013/Index`. Furthermore, if I perform a search from the new index, the new url is `/christmass-2013/Index?filter=Summer2014`

How can I configure it so I it leaves no trails?

Comment: If you move your 3rd route (the one containing url: "{slug}/{action}",) to the very end, do you still have this issue?

Comment: No, but I cannot create ActionLinks for slug now. `@Url.Action("Details", "Event", new { slug = Model.Slug})` goes to `/Events/Details?slug=christmass-2013` instead of `/christmass-2013`

Comment: Gotcha, saw that too in my testing.  Created a working example with explanation below.  Let me know if that works in your cases (assuming only seeing a small portion of your project)

Answer (score 2):

Route definitions can be finicky due to the order of processing and matching routes you didn't expect them to match.  I created a MVC app from scratch and was able to get your routes working as well as actually able to remove one.  First the code, then the explanation:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Profiles",
    url: "Profile/{userName}/{action}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Profile",
        action = "Index",
        userName = UrlParameter.Optional
});

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Pictures",
    url: "Picture/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Picture",
        action = "Index",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    });
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Events",
    url: "{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Event", action = "Index"},
    constraints: new { controller = "Event" });

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "EventBySlug",
    url: "{slug}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Event", action = "Details" });
```

First, since your fourth and fifth routes were essentially identical (sans the URL), we were able to combine those into my third route.  Second, we need your slug route to only be invoked when no other route matches, so we moved it to the last route (this takes care of the trail you mentioned).  Finally, since both my routes three and four could possibly be invoked (how do we know if it is a slug or a controller), there is a fourth parameter that essentially restricts what the value of "Controller" can be.  I don't know if you have any other controllers outside of Event, Profile, Picture, this assumes you do not.  Since Profile and Picture are already mapped in previous routes, we don't have to constrain them here.  However, if you have a Help controller or something similar, you would need to update my third route to

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Events",
  url: "{controller}/{action}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Event", action = "Index"},
  constraints: new { controller = "Event|Help" });
```

using the `|` operator as an `"OR"` - `controller must equal Event Or Help`.

Words of caution.  One, ensure a slug can never be the name of a controller, else a slug will try and map to a controller/action rather than details.  Two, if routing by slug, ensure that they are unique in your system, else you might pull the wrong data.

**EDIT**

It appears this routing configuration works as well for me (without constraints)

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "EventBySlug",
   url: "{slug}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Event", action = "Details" });

routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Events",
   url: "{controller}/{action}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Event", action = "Index"});
```

On index page:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Christmas 2013!", "Details", new {controller="Event", slug="Christmas-2013"})
```

returns URL: `http://localhost:11319/Christmas-2013`

My event details page: `@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Event")`

return URL: `http://localhost:11319/`

So basically I have determined there are a few possible ways to accomplish this.  It really depends on how complex some of your other URLs may be.

Comment: First, I really appreciate people like you that go into that trouble to help the community. So thanks!
Second, I have several controllers but it's not an issue to add them to the constraint.
And third, having to add each controller to that constraint by text is error prone, but if that works I'll go with it until I find a way to avoid that detail. I'll let you know if this solves my issue.

Comment: @odyodyodys I agree, but having the slug by itself without a controller prefix makes it a little tougher to route IMHO.  There may be a combination of constraints that could make this a little easier, or, you could use the Html.RouteLink and specify a specific route when using slugs that could prevent having to manually constrain on a controller name.

Comment: @odyodyodys - played with the route dictionary a little more, there may be an alternative that seems to work in my simple test project.  PS - thanks for helping my procrastinate, there is code I simply don't want to write today :)

Comment: The first answer of yours has 2 issues that I couldn't resolve:
 1. I cannot navigate to home eg: http://localhost:53724/
 2. I have the same issue as in my first comment bellow my question.

About your edit: Everything works fine, but you missed the fact that I want `{slug}/{action}` and not just `{slug}`. If I add action to the third rule, I get the same behavior with the `{slug}/Event/Create` that I described in my first comment bellow my question.

Comment: @odyodyodys - how would you ever have the URL `{slug}/Event/Create'.  Based on your route rules, shouldn't that be '{slug}/Create`?